# One time login/registration in magento multistore site

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, e-commerce

I have a site with two store.I want when user login in one store they automatically logged in for both store.
my site store are
site.com/store1
site.com/store2
currently user has to register and login separately for both the stores.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you active customer sharing? You can configure this here: System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Share Customer Accounts.

Comment: Yes i did.I set global option but still not working for me.

Comment: @James answer must work. Have you cleared your cache?